# upload a file to the server using SOAP in obj c

Tags: objective-c

How to upload a audio/video file to server using SOAP web service in Objective C?

Thanks
Praba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        NSData *voiceData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        voiceData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        if (voiceData)
        {

            NSLog(@"voiceData%@",voiceData);
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"voiceFile\"; filename=\"voice.caf\"\r\n"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:voiceData]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

1. Compose a XML SOAP request conforming the interface definitions of your server.
2. Post said request to your server.
3. There is no step 3.

Or try to use http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/.